# Draw 3D log likelihood plot in R

Tags: r

I want to try and use R to draw me a 3D log likelihood plot for a model with two parameters.

My function is given below:

```
  negL=function(theta,data){
    mu=theta[1]
    tau=theta[2]

  n11=data$ev.trt
  n12=data$n.trt-data$ev.trt
  n21=data$ev.ctrl
  n22=data$n.ctrl-data$ev.ctrl
  odds=(n11*n22)/(n12*n21)
  logodds=log(odds)
  varodds=(1/n11)+(1/n12)+(1/n21)+(1/n22)

  x=logodds
  sigma=varodds

  L=-(1/2)*sum(log((2*pi)*(sigma+tau)))-(1/2)*sum((((x-mu)^2))/(sigma+tau))
  return(-L)
  }
```

Here L is my likelihood function.

I want to try and draw the log likelihood plot based on this data:

```
          Author ev.ctrl n.ctrl ev.trt n.trt duration
1         RAPID1      15    199    146   393    6.150
2         RAPID2       4    127     80   246    5.850
3        Kim2007       9     63     28    65    6.850
4          DE019      19    200     81   207   10.950
5         ARMADA       5     62     37    67   11.650
6  Weinblatt1999       1     30     23    59   13.000
7          START      33    363    110   360    8.100
8         ATTEST      22    110     61   165    7.850
9        Abe2006       1     47     15    49    8.300
10    Strand2006       5     40      5    40   11.250
11      CHARISMA      14     49     26    50    0.915
12        OPTION      22    204     90   205    7.650
```

I have calculated maximum likelihood estimators of theta to be (1.6760569 0.2112315) using R optim()

Basically I am wanting mu to appear on the x axis, tau on the y axis and then the log likelihood -L on the z axis.

I tried adding this onto my function

```
  persp3d(negL, c(0,6), c(-1,3), col="red", xlab="mu", ylab="tau^2", zlab="Likelihood",
      main="Perspective plot of Likelihood")
```

from the rgl package after seeing it on another webpage but I am getting an error saying:

```
Error in (function (theta)  : 
  unused argument (c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, 
-0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96, -0.96,
```

when I try and run it.

Any ideas of how to do this and functions to use would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have added in the maximum likelihood estimators for mu and tau to the question.

Comment: Just been through and accepted the answers which helped me. Sorry I hadn't looked through the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
negL<- function(mu,tau,data){  
  n11=data$ev.trt
  n12=data$n.trt-data$ev.trt
  n21=data$ev.ctrl
  n22=data$n.ctrl-data$ev.ctrl
  odds=(n11*n22)/(n12*n21)
  logodds=log(odds)
  varodds=(1/n11)+(1/n12)+(1/n21)+(1/n22)
  x=logodds
  sigma=varodds
  L=-(1/2)*sum(log((2*pi)*(sigma+tau)))-(1/2)*sum((((x-mu)^2))/(sigma+tau))
  return(-L)
}
f <- Vectorize(negL,vectorize.args=c("mu","tau"))
library(rgl)
mu  <- seq(0,6,0.1)
tau <- seq(0,3,0.1)
z <- outer(mu,tau,f,data=data)
zlim    <- range(z[!is.na(z)])
palette <- rev(rainbow(20))
colors  <- palette[19*(z-zlim[1])/diff(zlim) + 1] 

persp3d(mu,tau,z,col=colors)
```

[image]

So there are a couple of issues.

First, `persp3d(...)` takes 3 arguments: `x` is a vector defining the x-axis, `y` is a vector defining the y-axis, and `z` is a *matrix* with dimensions length(x) x length(y) where each element is a value of `z` for that combination of `x` and `y`. You have to set up the vectors `x` and `y` and the matrix `z` (as in the code above).

One way to set up the `z` matrix is using the `outer(x,y,FUN)` function (read the documentation). This takes two vectors, `x`, and `y`, and returns the result of evaluating the function `FUN` on every combination of `x` and `y`. But it requires the `FUN` be *vectorized*, which your `negL(...)` is not. So we create a new function, `f(...)` which is a vectorized version of `negL(...)`.

Third, the function `negL(...)` has to take two arguments, `mu` and `tau`, rather than a vector with two elements (`theta`). So I changed the function's signature to do that. Other than that the function is identical to your question.

Finally, in your question you (seem to...) want to use negative values of `tau`. But `negL(...)` is undefined for `tau < 0`.